# errorThrown in Jquery Ajax Returns Undefined?

Tags: jquery, ajax

According to jQuery :

> When an HTTP error occurs, **errorThrown** receives the textual portion of
>   the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error."

http://jsfiddle.net/RafuW/9/

**Question:**

If so , Why  does it return an `undefined` error  code?

p.s. ( I `know` I can get the details for `not found` from the jqXHR obj - but still  -  I want an answer for the **errorThrown** part).

Comment: did you read my last line ??????

Comment: and the fiddle it should be like `type:'POST'` not `method:'POST'` and nope i got straight to the fiddle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the version of jQuery you're using doesn't support that argument. If use jQuery 1.5.2 in jsFiddle your code will return `NOT FOUND`.

Comment: so whats the difference between it and x.statusText ?

Comment: @Eris They're actually the same. jQuery populates one from the other.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you are using the latest version of jQuery, there's another reason why `errorThrown` could be empty: the request was made with HTTP/2.

This is because the property comes from the `statustext` property of the underlying XHR, and that property does not get populated for HTTP/2 requests.

More info here:
[Why is the statusText of my XHR empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41632077/why-is-the-statustext-of-my-xhr-empty)