# Extracting the errorThrown from my ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I haven't been able to retrieve the error message from my ajax call in order to figure out what the error is.

I've seen this question: [errorThrown in Jquery Ajax Returns Undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7865131/errorthrown-in-jquery-ajax-returns-undefined)

I copied that error call, but still no result.

```
grab_songs = function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: 'http://tangoalphatango.com/songs.php',
        succss: function(data) {
            $('#result').html('success');
        },
        error: function(x, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
$('.song-title').click(grab_songs);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms69K/2/

Why won't ajax give me an error message?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: if it is a cross domain call no errors are available per API docs `Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. `  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: It seems that `errorThrown` would only be populated if an HTTP error is found. And I think there are possibilities for non-HTTP errors

Comment: best place to start is in browser console...inspect the request itself for status, data sent/received etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({type:'POST',url:'/songs.php',data:{id:song},success:function(data){$('#lyrics').html(data);}});
```

The request is no longer failing, but I've no idea what changed. I was never able to capture an error message and the browser console never gave me an error either. All I can do is chalk it up to a server error.

Answer (score 0):

You've spelt success wrong. That could be the reason as your second post works when it is spelt correctly.

Comment: You're about two years too late on that one.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).